# Service Area polygon appears to fill in between the roads for areas it should not reach

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.5, service-area

In ArcMap 10.5.1, I have created a service area polygon of 1000m along a road network, with a trim of 50m. In the image you will see where the road is linked around, the inside is filled in (red circles). However there should be a hole in this area as it is outside of the trim and not reachable within the parameters.

I am using ArcGIS Network Analyst. After adding the Network Dataset I used the Network Analyst toolbar to create a new service area. I added Facilities, which was one single central point. Within Service Area layer properties I set the Impedance to 1000m, in the direction away from the facility. I chose to Generate Polygons - Detailed with a 50m trim. I also chose to generate a line.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS Network Analyst?  What were the precise steps (tools and parameter values) that you used in your workflow?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this bug description:
[Bug NIM066645](https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDY2NjQ1)

> *Network Analyst does not trim a Service Area polygon properly if the area is enclosed by a Network Analyst Route in versions 9.3.1 SP2 and
>   10.0 SP1. If trim option is only meant to trim the exterior of the service area, then please update the documentation to reflect this
>   behavior.*

So this seems to be the expected behaviour, but the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/service-area.htm) is not crystal clear (is 'periphery' only the outer border of the service area or does it also include 'islands').